# Magento 2 : Override cart item default template?

Tags: magento2.2, cart-items

I am overriding cart item default template in custom module. Below are code of layout file and template file. It does not work.

**app/code/Vendor/Custom/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_item_price_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="Vendor_Custom::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="Vendor_Custom::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Custom/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml**

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer */

$_item = $block->getItem();
$product = $_item->getProduct();
$isVisibleProduct = $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
/** @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $helper */
$helper = $this->helper('Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data');
$canApplyMsrp = $helper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($product) && $helper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product);
?>
<tbody class="cart item">
    <tr class="item-info">
        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Item1')) ?>" class="col item">
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl() ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>"
                   tabindex="-1"
                   class="product-item-photo">
            <?php else:?>
                <span class="product-item-photo">
            <?php endif;?>
            <?= $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml() ?>
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                </a>
            <?php else: ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="product-item-details">
                <strong class="product-item-name">
                    <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl() ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?></a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </strong>
                <p><strong>Note:</strong> This is a renewal product.</p>
                <?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()):?>
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $block->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                            <dt><?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </dd>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </dl>
                <?php endif;?>
                <?php if ($messages = $block->getMessages()): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
                        <div class="cart item message <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $message['type'] ?>"><div><?= $block->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></div></div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
                <?php if ($addInfoBlock): ?>
                    <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </td>

        <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
            <td class="col msrp" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>">
                <span class="pricing msrp">
                    <span class="msrp notice"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('See price before order confirmation.') ?></span>
                    <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                    <a href="#" class="action help map" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($helpLinkId) ?>" data-mage-init='{"addToCart":{"helpLinkId": "#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $helpLinkId ?>","productName": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $product->getName() ?>","showAddToCart": false}}'>
                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __("What's this?") ?></span>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </td>
        <?php else: ?>
            <td class="col price" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>">
                <?= $block->getUnitPriceHtml($_item) ?>
            </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <td class="col qty" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>">
            <div class="field qty">
                <label class="label" for="cart-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-qty">
                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control qty">
                    <input id="cart-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-qty"
                           name="cart[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
                           data-cart-item-id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getSku() ?>"
                           value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getQty() ?>"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>"
                           class="input-text qty"
                           data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
                           data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="col subtotal" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal')) ?>">
            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <span class="cart msrp subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?= $block->getRowTotalHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item-actions">
        <td colspan="100">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getActions($_item) ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a file to your module but for same, you have to override particular block in your module then only you can override form your module.

**File should be here instead of in your module.**
1)app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

2)app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

Comment: I want to override it in module not in theme.

Comment: ok then override Block also then set that block in XML so it worked

Answer (score 0):

we can change the template of the block. below are the 3 ways to achieve it

Example 1: using the template attribute

```
 <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" template="%Namespace_Module::new_template.phtml%"/>
```

Example 2: using the  instruction

```
 <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
   <arguments>
     <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">%Namespace_Module::new_template.phtml%</argument>
   </arguments>
 </referenceBlock>
```

Example 3: using the  instruction

```
 <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
   <action method="setTemplate">
     <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">%Namespace_Module::new_template.phtml%</argument>
   </action>
 </referenceBlock>
```